# alternative red blue green in python plot to display percentage contribution

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, colors

I have three percentages value and would like to display them in a single colour. But the colour triangle for [red, green, blue]  creates [this subtractive color RGB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN6VH.png) which has a very dull colour in the middle and you can't really distinguish between red and blue and between red and green. Is there way to have an [additive color RGB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD7nC.jpg) which is easier to see the difference? Thanks.

Please note that the colour for red, green and blue must be between 0 and 1. This is my code

col1 = [red, green, blue]

```
box= plt.boxplot([data1, data2,data3,data4,data5],1, '', 0, 0.15,  patch_artist=True)



colors = [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5]
for patch, color in zip(box['boxes'], colors):
patch.set_facecolor(color)
```

Comment: So just subtract the values from (255, 255, 255)?

Comment: I'd think if you put it this way [pct_val1, pct_val2, pct_val3] you already have it additive. Do you have a particular way of plotting/rendering in mind?

Comment: you can't subtract the value, the value allowed is only between 0 and 1